# What happens If the version of the image is not specified while running a container

Tags: docker, containers

What will happen if the version of the image is not specified while running the container?

Will it not run the container **OR** will it pick the latest version **OR** will it run all containers for all different versions present?

Comment: default image tag is `latest`. it will be different if you run the container at different time.

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't specify the image version, it will be pulling the image with latest tag. However, the latest tag doesn't always referring to the latest version of code

Answer (score -1):

If the tag of the image is not specified while running the container, it will by default pull the image with the `latest` tag and run the container